# Chrome freezes when loading page

Tags: javascript, html, apache, google-chrome

I am running a website off of an Apache2 server, and am having some problems with Google Chrome. Sometimes, the main page loads fine, and other times chrome gets "stuck", and a small box with the text `waiting for domain` or `processing request` appears in the bottom-left corner.

However, this problem doesn't happen in Firefox. Furthermore, any page besides the main page (example.com/something) loads without a problem. When the main page is stuck, if I try to open the javascript console, chrome freezes. I am using Chrome beta, but this problem also happens in non-beta browsers.

Comment: Are there any (ugly) scripts on that page?

Comment: Try opening the console before you load the page. Specially the network tab, perhaps.

Comment: the page loads about 20 javascript files. Originally, there were more, but I compressed many of them into a single javascript file.

Comment: If I open the console first, it still freezes. It loads a few html elements, and then stops.

Comment: same for me on MacOs with chrome 65

Answer (score 0):

It may be AdBlock. Try to disable it and see the result.

For me it was similar, sometimes Google Chrome freezed on page load.